# Trying to align input field

Tags: html, css, layout, input

I'm having some trouble trying to align this input field. Here is the screenshot

http://i255.photobucket.com/albums/hh140/testament1234/input_zps68391b01.png

Here is my HTML -

```
<div class="four columns search_box">
   <form>
       <input type="text" placeholder="SEARCH"/>
   </form>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
.search_box input{
display:block;
vertical-align:middle
}
```

I have tried adding line-height but that seems incorrect. The height of container is 90px

Here is the Markup for the Header

```
<div class="container">
<header>

<div class="twelve columns">

   <h1 ><a class="logo" href="#" title="My Phone">my | phone</a></h1>
       <ul class="menu">
           <li><a href="#">press</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">downloads</a></li>
           <li class="noborder"><a href="#"><span>stores</span></a></li>
       </ul>
</div>

<!--SEARCH BOX -->
<div class="four columns search_box">
   <form>
       <input type="text" placeholder="SEARCH"/>
   </form>
</div>

</header>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to align the search box with the menu?  Are you using Zurb Foundation?  If so, would be good to see the HTML code for the menu too

Comment: @clestcruz where should they be aligning to? Press | Download | stores?  Do both (Press | Download | Stores) and the search_box have the same parent div?

Comment: Yes i want it to align properly with the menu. I'm only using skeleton framework

Answer (score 0):

I presume that your logo is supposed to sit above the menu and the search box.
Given that, I'd suggest having the logo inside a `div class="sixteen columns"` and then having the menu inside a `<div class="twelve columns">` so it fits the grid alongside the `<div class="four columns">` on the next row.  Like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <header>

        <!--LOGO-->
        <div class="sixteen columns">
            <h1 ><a class="logo" href="#" title="My Phone">my | phone</a></h1>
        </div>

        <!--NAVIGATION -->
        <div class="twelve columns">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#">press</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">downloads</a></li>
                <li class="noborder"><a href="#"><span>stores</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!--SEARCH BOX -->
        <div class="four columns search_box">
            <form>
                <input type="text" placeholder="SEARCH"/>
            </form>
        </div>

    </header>
</div>
```

Then it's just CSS tweaks to line up the menu text with the search text.

I've put it into a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/YR7Em/